# why get_where() function not working, while get() does the job which it shouldn't

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord

I am using codeigniter active record class.

What I am trying here is calling `get_users` method from controller with parameter `$user_id`.

If `$user_id` is `null` get me all the entries from users table otherwise it should give me the entries that match the array passed with `get_where()` method.

But `get_where` method is not working instead `get()` method does the purpose with same parameters. Why would that happen? Thanks.

```
public function get_users($user_id=null)
{
    if($user_id === null){
        $q = $this->db->get('users');

    }
    elseif (is_array($user_id)) {
        $q = $this->db->get('users', $user_id); 
        //$q = $this->db->get_where('users', $user_id); // not working
        $result = $q->row_array();
    }

    return $q->result_array();      
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your usage of `get_where()` is wrong:

It should be:

`$q = $this->db->get_where('users', array('userid_fieldname_in_table'=>$user_id));`

The second parameter should be an associative array where the key is the table's fieldname and the value is the value to look for.

Since you are passing an array it is better to use:

`$this->db->where_in('filename', $array_of_values());`

You can read [more in the documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html)

Comment: I am passing an array as the second parameter. is that right?

Comment: @RaihanMahmud - you are welcome, hope it helps. get_where is only for basic where clauses. For more detailed conditions (like using AND, OR) there are other functions in CI ActiveRecord